# Hows does this site do custom color?

Tags: javascript, css

I am starting out teaching myself web development.

I am trying to add an option for the person using the site to create custom colors when creating a stats bar.

I have found a website that is doing a similar thing for badges - http://streambadge.com

I have looked through the code but being new to javascript I can't understand what it's doing. I cant store the users color selections because my website won't have the user login. So something similar to this would be good.

Could someone explain how this website is doing the custom color option? Or if there is a particular name for what it is doing so that I can research it?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: That particular thing is called server-side scripting...

Comment: Their JavaScript is minified/obfuscated, so it would be difficult to make sense of. If you specifically mean the HTML color picker, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replies. No the color picker is fine. Im on about the way it stores the colors picking in the url then creates them custom colors. Is the CSS file reading from the URL or is it creating another CSS. I dont get how it works :(

Comment: @ChrisWright Are you talking about the resulting image embed that is created? There's a server-side script that's opaque to us, it's responding with a png file that is generated based on the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood, you want to store a color preference in the URL. Aside from server-side scripting, which is what those website usually use, this can be achieved using URL parameters and Javascript's URL object :

```
//url : https://mywebpage.com/index.html?color=blue;
let url = new URL(location.href);
let color = url.searchParams.get("color");
//returns "blue"
```

However, that code might not work for older browsers. If you want your code to work for IE8 and such, you might want to manually parse the url :

```
//url : https://mywebpage.com/index.html?color=blue;
let url = location.href;
let param = "color";
let color = url.split("").splice(url.indexOf(param + "=") + 1 + param.length, url.length-url.indexOf(param + "=") + 1 + param.length).join("");
//returns "blue"
```

You can then use that information to modify the CSS code through JS. For example :

```
document.body.backgroundColor = color;
document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].color = color;
document.getElementById("content").color = color;
```

As for how their server-side code works, there's no way to be sure as it can't be accessed, but It probably is something similar.